# outlier detection in time serie without using windows

Tags: time-series, outlier

I would like to know if it's possible to detect outliers in a time-serie with an outlier score computed given the whole dataset and not given windows

Comment: The whole dataset is just a special case of window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove trend and seasonality and check whether the time series is stationary. If it is, you can calculate mean ($\mu$) and standard deviation ($\sigma$). Now for each data point, you calculate the distance from the mean ($\|y-\mu\|$) and check if it exceeds some threshold. The default value for threshold is $3 \sigma$ what comes from three-sigma rule motivated by the assumption about the normality of the data (residuals after time series decomposition in our case). You can choose any threshold which is reasonable for you. One solution is to find the distribution of the data and derive a rule for this particular distribution.

Comment: my serie is unevenly time spaced , is it okay to use this rule, can I use the MAD score for detecting outliers?